# How to find an element outside div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click the button it print a text to the nearest class "print". Can anybody help me please.

**HTML :**

```
<div class ="row">
  <div id = "div1">
     <div class ="col-md-12">
         <button class ="button">print</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="div2">
     <div class ="print">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class ="row">
  <div id = "div1">
     <div class ="col-md-12">
         <button class ="button">print</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="div2">
     <div class ="print">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `.print` do you mean by 'the closest'? Presumably the one in the same `.row`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your answer is this:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
  var text = $(e.target).closest(".row").find(".print").text();

  alert(text)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `closest() or parents()` to go up to the parent `div` with class `row` then find the element with class `print` using `find()` method and get finally get the text using `text()` :

```
$("button").on('click', function(e){
   console.log( $(this).closest(".row").find(".print").text() );
   //Or
   console.log( $(this).parents(".row").find(".print").text() );
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("button").on('click', function(e){
  console.log( $(this).parents(".row").find(".print").text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="row">
  <div id = "div1">
    <div class ="col-md-12">
      <button class ="button">print</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="div2">
    <div class ="print">Print div 1 content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class ="row">
  <div id = "div1">
    <div class ="col-md-12">
      <button class ="button">print</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="div2">
    <div class ="print">Print div 2 content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```